# Remove accents/diacritics in search form

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know where to put

```py
import unicodedata

unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

here

**Edit:**

I should immediately paste all the code.

```py
from BTCInput import *

class Contact:
    pass

contacts = []

def new_contact():
    print('new contact')
    new_contact = Contact()
    new_contact.name = read_text('name: ')
    new_contact.address = read_text('address: ')
    new_contact.telephone = read_text('phone: ')
    contacts.append(new_contact)

def find_contact():
    print('find contact')
    search_name = read_text('name: ')
    search_name = search_name.strip()
    search_name = search_name.lower()
    result = None
    for contact in contacts:
        name = contact.name
        name = name.strip()
        name = name.lower()
        if name.startswith(search_name):
            result = contact
            break

    if result != None:
        print(f'name: {result.name}\n'
              f'Address: {result.address}\n'
              f'phone: {result.telephone}\n')
    else:
        print('xyz')

while True:
    menu = int(input('name'))
    if menu == 1:
        new_contact()
    elif menu == 2:
        find_contact()
```

So... I want from the search form to ignore the diacritics.
I don't want to change the code 'cause it's an example from the book which I'm actually reading. I just want to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
from unidecode import unidecode
def find_contact(contacts):
    print('Find contact')
    search_name = input('Enter the name: ')
    search_name = search_name.strip()
    search_name = search_name.lower()
    search_name = unidecode(search_name)
    all_contacts_name=[]
    for key,values in contacts.items():
        for contact in values:
            name = contact["name"]
            name = name.strip()
            name = name.lower()
            all_contacts_name.append(name)

    if search_name in all_contacts_name:
        print("this contact exists")

    else:
        print("this contact does not exisit")

find_contact({"contacts":[{"name":"xxxx"},{"name":"ZOLC"}]})
```

output:

```
Enter the name: ŻÓŁĆ
this contact exists
```

Comment: in this example  i used a dict of contacts as in put {"contacts":{"name":"ZOLC"}} you can switch the value of this dict to a list of keys in such list you find the name of the contact ; i will edit the code to get this new format as improvement

Comment: thanks but you know... I wanted to solve it like in the question.
the code is an example from book which I'm actually reading and I don't wanna change too much there.

Comment: you tolk about the use of unicodedata or the ue of a simple list in the input @Sevy

Comment: so i will check this and replay you @Sevy